# How to set tabBarItem's badge from AppDelegate.m (tabBarView is not root View)

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I can change badge value in AppDelegate.m by following code:

```
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
[[tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"Badge";
```

Only if the tabBarViewController is window's root view controller.

However, in my new program, tabBarController is not root view.

I have tried following code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarController"] ;
[[tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"Badge";
```

It just won't work. tabBarItem doesn't show any badge.

**EDIT-**

I have added following code to check does tabController created or not, The answer is YES.

```
if (tabController) {
     NSLog(@"tabController has been created ");
}else {
     NSLog(@"You have a null reference - The Object hasn't been created yet");
}
```

The answer is YES.

> 2013-03-01 11:57:00.600 Reporting[14854:907] tabControllerhas been
>   created

**But, the expected badge still does not show up.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this code Mr. Robert

```
       [[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0] setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", notificationCount ]];
```

Comment: Sorry, the current controller is not tabBarController, it is xxxAppDelegate.m   So, I can't use [self tabBarController]

Comment: you can do this in an viewcontroller of tabbarcontrolle

Comment: In my condition, I can't do this in the tabBarControler. I have to setBadgeVlaue in other controller.